# Generic netlink - PID not thread unique

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, netlink

I'm writing kernel module that receives messages from userspace via generic netlink. When I access genl_info->snd_pid, in kernel callback function, I get process ID.

According to libnl documentation:

> libnl generates unique port numbers based on the process identifier and adds an offset to it allowing for multiple sockets to be used. The initial socket will still equal to the process identifier for backwards compatibility reasons.

My userspace application uses multiple threads and I need to differentiate them. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two options:

1. Share one netlink socket through all the threads, but use your own generic netlink protocol's NLA to identify the thread
2. Open own netlink socket in every thread and use the following trick:

The current `PID_MAX_LIMIT` == 2 ^ 22, while the `pid` field is of type `uint32`. So one can use `pid` to pack together the process' pid and some id <= 1024. Pls refer to samples: [in C](https://github.com/thom311/libnl/blob/master/lib/socket.c#L65), (libnl) and [in Python](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2/blob/0.3.8/pyroute2/netlink/nlsocket.py#L816) (pyroute2).